# MySQL.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

I am new in Python and MySQL. 
I want to create a login which fetch the data from db. I am using Tkinter as Python GUI.

Here is my snipped of code.

```
def login(self):
    login_username = username.get()
    login_password = password.get()

    #connect to db
    db = mysql.connector.connect(host = 'localhost', user = 'root', password = '', database = 'user')

    #create a cursor
    mycursor = db.cursor()

    #if (login_username.get() == "" or login_password.get() == ""):
        #messagebox.showinfo("", "Please complete the required field")
    #else:

    loop = 'true'
    while(loop == 'true'):
        if(mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM useraccess WHERE user_type, password VALUES (%s, %s)", (login_username, login_password))):
            db.commit()
            messagebox.showinfo("", "Successfully Login")
        else:
            db.commit()
            messagebox.showerror("", "Invalid username or password")


    #commit
    #db.commit()
```

Meanwhile, when I run this code, it shows an error which is
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' password VALUES ('d', 'ddddd')' at line 1

Here is my database: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Big9.png

Anyone can help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Change the filtering condition syntax: `WHERE user_type = %s and password = %s`

Comment: i change it already, but now it shows an error message which is mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found

Comment: Look up the python API on using libraries. `execute` doesn't return what you think it does. You don't need `commit` statements on `SELECT`. And don't store plain text passwords.

Comment: @Eve11 "PASSWORD" is a mysql keyword, don't use it as a table/column name. As you see it gets confused because the "PASSWORD" command doesn't make sense there.

Comment: @danblack it works, thank you so much for your help

Comment: @Progman ah i see, okay, i'll change it to another name then. thank you for the information